# Como contar la profundidad de un array e ir contando la cantidad de Number , boleanos ,string y undefined que tiene. javascript

Tags: javascript, array, string

El planteamiento del problema es el siguiente:

La función countDeep recibe por parámetro un arreglo que contiene numbers, strings, booleanos, undefined y/o arreglos
(este ultimo contienen, a su vez, más numbers, strings, booleanos, undefined y/o arreglos).

Deberás contar la cantidad de cada uno y realizar las siguientes operaciones para llegar al resultado final.
la cantidad de arrays (contando el array padre) menos la cantidad de numbers, al resultado multiplicarlo por la cantidad de strings,
al resultado dividirlo por la cantidad de booleanos y a ese resultado elevarlo a la cantidad de undefined.

Ejemplo:

```
countDeep( [ 1, 2, 3, ["hi"], [ undefined, "hola", [ true, "bye" ] ], undefined, [ false ], "9"] ) ----> Debería retornar 2
        // number = 3, string = 4, boolean = 2, undefined = 2, array = 5:
        // la ecuacion quedaria 5-3 = 2, 2*4 = 8, 8/2 = 4, 4^2 ------> resultado = 16
```

Mi problema es que no me cuenta la cantidad correcta de numbers ,string ,boolean y undefined. Para finalmente hacer la ecuación correspondiente.

El código es el siguiente:

```
function countDeep(arr) {
  

let num = 0;
let str = 0;
let bol = 0;
let und = 0;
let count = 1;
let result = 0;

 for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
      count += countDeep(arr[i])
   }
   if(typeof arr[i] === "number") num++
  
   if(typeof arr[i] === "string") str++
   
   if(typeof arr[i] === "boolean") bol++
  
   if(arr[i] === undefined){
     und++
   } 
   result = (((count - num)*str)/bol)^und;
 }
  return result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu error es hacer la función completa recursiva para realizar el conteo. La función completa no te devuelve la cantidad de arreglos que hay, por lo que hacer `count += countDeep(arr[i])` es uno de los errores que tienes. El otro, es que el operador `^` no es la potenciación en javascript.

La solución no requiere mucha modificación en tu código. Lo único que hice fue implementar la recursividad con una función interna para contar todos los tipos de datos que hay. Finalmente calculé la operación final. El código queda:

```js
function countDeep(arr) {
    let num = 0;
    let str = 0;
    let bol = 0;
    let und = 0;
    let count = 1;

    function countDeepInner(arr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (Array.isArray(arr[i])) {
                count++;
                countDeepInner(arr[i])
            }
            if (typeof arr[i] === "number") num++

            if (typeof arr[i] === "string") str++

            if (typeof arr[i] === "boolean") bol++

            if (arr[i] === undefined) {
                und++
            }
        }
    }

    countDeepInner(arr);
    console.log(`Arrays: ${count}`);
    console.log(`Numbers: ${num}`);
    console.log(`Strings: ${str}`);
    console.log(`Booleans: ${bol}`);
    console.log(`Undefined: ${und}`);

    return Math.pow(((count - num) * str) / bol, und);
}


let result = countDeep([1, 2, 3, ["hi"], [undefined, "hola", [true, "bye"]], undefined, [false], "9"])

console.log(`Resultado: ${result}`);

console.log(`----------------------`);
let result2 =  countDeep([ "x",undefined, "b", "c", 4, "hi", [ 1, "a",true, "hola", [ "o",undefined, "n"] ], "6",[[["3"]]],false,"ma",undefined, [ 0 ], 200])
console.log(`Resultado: ${result2}`);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar el codigo, no me cuenta el numero correcto de cada cosa que me pide. Deberia contar la profundidad de nuestro array y realizar las ecuaciones correspondientes.  countDeep([ "x",undefined, "b", "c", 4, "hi", [ 1, "a",true, "hola", [ "o",undefined, "n"] ], "6",[[["3"]]],false,"ma",undefined, [ 0 ], 200])

Comment: Especificamente no me toma lo que esta dentro en los array del array , me toma los datos del array principal unicamente

Comment: @LuchoMuga No se a qué te refieres. Acabo de probarlo con lo que dices y funciona perfectamente. ¿Qué salida esperas? Yo veo que cuenta perfectamente: Arrays: 7, Numbers: 4, Strings: 11, Booleans: 2, Undefined: 3, Resultado: 4492.125.

Comment: Es necesario usar clousures ?? cuando haces la function countDeepInner(arr) ? y finalmente la ultima duda que tengo es que antes del ultimo return vos llamas nuevamente a la funcion porque ??

Comment: @LuchoMuga los closures es lo que garantiza que la cuenta se mantenga y que no se resetee. Garantiza además que la función interna tenga acceso a las variables. Antes del último return en realidad llamo a la función la primera vez. Antes solo la estaba declarando.

Comment: mala mia Jaime... me perdi con los nombres ;)

Comment: Claro es como que hacemos recursion el el primer condicional para cuando se cuentre con un array y al final antes del return con el Mat.pow ,para verificar una ultima vez no ?

Comment: En realidad `countDeep` no es recursiva. La función recursiva es `countDeepInner`. Si `countDeep` fuera recursiva, reseteara las variables en cada invocación. Tal vez es complicado verlo para ti ahora que estás empezando, pero en Programación Orientada a Objetos, es totalmente normal tener una función privada auxiliar para ayudar a hacer los cálculos y segmentar el trabajo.

Comment: Genial ahora me quedo mas claro muchas gracias jaime.