# ¿como puedo hacer que la función me retorne el valor correcto por separado de cada propiedad?

Tags: javascript

La función countDeep recibe por parámetro un arreglo que contiene numbers, strings, booleanos, undefined y/o arreglos
(este ultimo contienen, a su vez, más numbers, strings, booleanos, undefined y/o arreglos).
la función debe contar y retornar la cantidad de cada uno

```
function countDeep(arr){
let num = 0,
str = 0,
bool= 0,
undef= 0,
array = 1;
  
  function countDeepInner(arr){
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      
      if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
        
        array++;
        
        countDeepInner(arr[i]);
      
      }else{

        if (typeof arr[i] === 'string') return ++str;
        
        if (typeof arr[i] === 'boolean') return ++bool;

        if (typeof arr[i] === 'number') return ++num;

        if (typeof arr[i] === 'undefined') return ++undef;
      
      } 
    }        
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Y que has intentado, recuerda que cada pregunta debe tener un [Ejemplo demostrable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como contar la profundidad de un array e ir contando la cantidad de Number , boleanos ,string y undefined que tiene. javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/538746/como-contar-la-profundidad-de-un-array-e-ir-contando-la-cantidad-de-number-bol)

Comment: Sugerencia, cada vez que les den tarea, copien y peguen el enunciado en los buscadores. He perdido la cuenta de las preguntas duplicadas por los estudiantes del mismo curso. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

compañero me pareció interesante tu ejercicio, yo lo hice de esta forma, espero y te ayude.

```
function countDeep(arr){
    let num = 0;
    let str = 0;
    let bool = 0;
    let undef = 0;
    let arr2 = 0;
    
    arr.forEach((element,i) => {
        
        if(Array.isArray(arr[i])){
            arr2++;
        }else if (typeof arr[i] === 'string'){
            str++;
        }else if (typeof arr[i] === 'number'){
            num++;
        }else if (typeof arr[i] === 'boolean'){
            bool++;
        }else if (typeof arr[i] === 'undefined'){
            undef++;
        }
    });
    console.log(`numeros: ${num}, strings: ${str}, booleans: ${bool}, undefined: ${undef}, arrays: ${arr2}`);
}

countDeep([1,2,[],4,[],5,false,true,'hola','chao',true,undefined,3,2,undefined]);
```